# Advice on closing questions as duplicates

Tags: discussion, closing, exact-duplicates, advice

In a very [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009244/prove-fracxy32xyz-fracyz32xyz-fraczx32xyz-gt-frac15) the OP had made considerable amount of progress in proving an inequality. The OP was only left to prove  the inequality $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x\le \frac{4}{27}$. Myself knowing that the inequality was quite famous (at least in the contest world). I voted to close it as duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653574/prove-4x-y-z3-27x2y-y2z-z2x) one which helped the OP finish the proof. (And he/she acknowledges it.)

Thinking over it, I don't know whether what I did was correct. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653574/prove-4x-y-z3-27x2y-y2z-z2x) post with which it has been associated as a duplicate is very different from the original question and it has particularly helped the OP. I really don't know whether I should have closed as a duplicate. Please advice

Should I have answered the question with the link?
Or should I have just left it as a comment?

Also in general is it a practice in the site to close questions as a duplicate taking into account the OP's progress? (For example, in this case associating it with a post concerning a sub-inequality the OP was left to prove)

Comment: It looks like a good outcome to me.  As the Question itself has a good bit of reasoning and is upvoted, it  is likely to remain as a duplicate.  In that way it will perhaps serve to direct interested Readers to the older Question for further information (obviating a duplication of efforts unnecessarily).

Comment: I wonder why you have [removed the tag related to duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/33104/revisions) when the question is clearly about closing as duplicates?

Comment: @MartinSleziak I tried to bring in the tag duplicates but it seems the  system is automatically changing it to 'exact duplicates ' which is not the case

Comment: @MartinSleziak If my question was about 'exact duplicates' I should obviously close it,in this case they are not ,My confusion is what should I do if the post indirectly adresses the question as in this case.please help me to put the right tag

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I would suggest to continue the discussion related to the choice of tags [in the tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2021/2/3), so that we do not leave too many comments here.

Comment: This post seems a bit related: [Handling near duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6941). (Maybe also [other posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/6941) might be useful.) But it is definitely not the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely a judgement call - so various users might have various views on a specific question.

One issue is whether you consider this a question about the inequality
$$\frac{x}{y^3+2xyz} + \frac{y}{z^3+2xyz} + \frac{z}{x^3+2xyz} \gt \frac{15}{2} \tag{1}$$
or whether you consider this a question whether about the inequality $$xy^2+yz^2+zx^2 < \frac{4}{27} \tag{2}.$$
(The OP writes that it suffices to prove $(2)$ to finish their approach)

If you consider this as a question about $(2)$, then it is an exact duplicate. If it is a question about $(1)$ then personally, I would consider a reasonable thing:

- Posting an answer saying where solution for $(2)$ can be found. (Thus finishing the OP's approach.)
- Leaving the question open, so that if somebody has entirely different approach to $(1)$, they still can post another answer.

In general, if we have question about some problem $(1)$ and we want to close it as a duplicate of a question about the problem $(2)$, we should have a look whether these two problems are close enough to each other. But I do not want to rehash here the previous discussions about this issue, I wrote about this at length here: [How close a match we need to close a recurring question as a duplicate?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23458#23472)

In this specific case, letting the question closed might be a reasonable outcome too.. Mainly because the OP agreed with the closure. (The fact that it is shown as [closed by community](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4009244/revisions) means that this was chosen by the OP after the duplicate was suggested.) And if somebody wants to post a different approach as an answer, they can ask for the question to be reopened or simply post a new question.

Comment: thanks for writing this up,one question: you mentioned an alternative of posting an answer saying where solution 2 can be found,I felt that was a good idea but are link only answers encouraged in this site?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that the link answers are frowned upon. However, this is a bit special situation - since the OP says that they have already been able to get from $(1)$ to $(2)$ and they only need that to finish their approach. Here are some examples of my answers which consist mostly of links: [$x^y = y^x$ for integers $x$ and $y$y](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9505#78599), [Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Prove that every Hamel basis of $X$ is uncountable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/217516#217843) (Although it is not the same situation as in this question.)

Comment: Ok thanks I think if a similar case comes I shall answer with a link.Thanks for your input and the various links you have collected

Comment: @Albus:  When we say "link only answers" are discouraged, there is an emphasis on "only".  Links are often used in Answers.  When they are used the FAQ on [how to write a good answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) discusses **providing context for links**.  The mention of external links there applies (perhaps to a lesser extent) to linking to previous Questions at Math.SE.